# 'PyJWT' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I was able to decode JWT in either `CMD` or `PowerShell` and get a JSON result:

```
pyjwt decode --no-verify eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
```

However, after re-installing Python a few times, this no longer works and I'm getting 'pyjwt' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Things I've tried:

1. Reinstall Python 3.8.x from installer
2. Reinstall Python 3.8.x from Microsoft Store
3. Checked `PATH` Environment Variable to Python.exe
4. Reinstall PyJWT using `pip install pyjwt`
5. Tried installing pyjwt version 1.4.0, 1.7.1, and 2.0.1, same problem

Is there something I'm missing from my Environment Variables?  I'm not sure why it's no longer working.  http://pypi.org/project/PyJWT/1.7.1. shows this example under `Decoding examples`, and my command looks like the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well

Try to add Python folder/Script to PATH by using instruction on this https://www.google.co.th/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/&ved=2ahUKEwjM1fXu9pXwAhWyxTgGHeJKDpIQFjAKegQIGxAC&usg=AOvVaw0PG5BF3E1K_EAiJneUN07T

Comment: In my case, the path to `pyjwt.exe` was here: `C:\Users\%username%\appdata\roaming\python\python38\Scripts`.  After adding this path to my local PATH environment variable, it worked as expected.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`pip show pyjwt` may show you where the package was installed.  Then add whatever path that contains the pyjwt executable to your environment path variable

Answer (score 0):

The command pyjwt has been dropped since 2.0.0:
https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst#v200

See "Drop CLI":

> Dropped the included cli entry point

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32061339)